# Number of real roots in quadratic equation with modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For $x\in\mathbb{R},$ The number of real roots of the equation $\displaystyle 3x^2-4|x^2-1|+x-1=0$ is

What i Try : I have solve it using cases ::

$\bullet \;$ For $x<-1\cup x>1,$ Then

$3x^2-4(x^2-1)+x-1=0$

$\displaystyle x^2-x-3=0\Longrightarrow x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$

$\bullet \; $ For $-1\leq x\leq 1$, Then

$\displaystyle x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{141}}{14}$

So we get $4$ real roots

Can we solve it without forming cases

Please explain me. Thanks

Comment: I can't see a way to do it without using two cases. And indeed you've done it correctly. I'd say you're good.

Comment: You do need to check whether each of those 4 roots fall belong in the corresponding case (it is not immediately obvious in this square root form) but here they all do, so they are 4 valid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that we may use the intermediate value theorem.

Let $f(x):=3x^2-4|x^2-1|+x-1$.

Then, we have $$f(-2)\lt 0,\ \ f(-1)\gt 0,\ \ f(0)\lt 0,\ \ f(1)\gt 0,\ \ f(3)\lt 0$$

Since $y=f(x)$ is continuous, we can say, by the the intermediate value theorem, that there are four real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=f(d)=0$$
$$-2\lt a\lt -1\lt b\lt 0\lt c\lt 1\lt d\lt 3$$

Since $f(x)=0$ cannot have more than four real roots, the number of real roots of $f(x)=0$ is $\color{red}4$.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the absolute value to one side then square both sides to get a new equation with potentially extraneous roots.

$3x^2-4|x^2-1|+x-1=0$.

$3x^2+x-1=4|x^2-1|$

$9x^4+x^2+1+6x^3-6x^2-2x=16x^4-32x^2+16$

$-7x^4+6x^3+27x^2-2x-15=(x^2-x-3)(-7x^2-x+5)=0$

Then solve the two quadratics.